# WCF Service with Message Level Encryption over HTTPS

Tags: wcf, encryption, message

I have seen one or two questions about this but no definite answers.  I have a customer requirement to implement a WCF-based client/server solution using Message Encryption AND HTTPS.  I understand that WCF doesn't support this as standard, and the options are HTTP with Message Encryption, HTTPS without Message Encryption, or HTTPS with Message Credentials.

None of these will satisfy the customer requirement.  I have control over both the service and the desktop-based clients.   The service is hosted at my location and the clients access it over the internet.

I have dug around for days (and nights :( ) trying out custom bindings and so on, but whenever I try to combine message encryption with Https, I come up against this error:

"The binding contains both a SymmetricSecurityBindingElement and a secure transport binding element. Policy export for such a binding is not supported."

I would prefer to user username/password for authentication but I am prepared to use client certificates if this makes it possible.  So far I haven't found any combination which is acceptable to WCF.

Is there any way to achieve this or am I just wasting my time?  I would value a quick answer because my customer's deadline is drawing very near!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731884(v=vs.110).aspx), the special `both` mode for security (meaning both message and transport) is only supported in the `NetMsmqBinding` binding, which I'm guessing, is not an option for you. Does your client happen to be the NSA? (Just wondering why anyone would need their communication encrypted twice).

Comment: Thanks - no it's not the NSA, just a slightly paranoid financial institution :)

I've seen the MSMQ option but it wouldn't be applicable in this case.  I'm coming round to the idea of implementing IMessageInspector and doing my own encryption.  That way I can use Transport security (SSL) but still encrypt the message body independently.

Not my preferred solution but I haven't seen a viable alternative so far.

Answer (score 0):

OK I've found a solution ...

Using IMessageInspector I intercepted the incoming and outgoing messages so that they can be encrypted and decrypted.  Encryption uses a symmetric technique - best because asymmetric only allows encryption of short strings and is very slow.

The downside is that both ends need to have the private key of the certificate - so the cert needs to be installed on both client and server machines (or the key could be placed in config).  This works for me though because the number of users is limited and all are under the control of the IT dept.

If I had more time I would have looked at setting up a second SSL connection with a different cert, purely to handle the certificate negotiation and avoid placing the cert on the client machine. Using SslStream was a possibility but I wasn't sure whether I could access key information to use for my own encryption, or whether this is held privately within SslStream class.

For now I'm just pleased to have it working before my deadline (only just though :) ) ...